# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException Dynamics CRM C# lookup field error

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying to create a new record in Dynamics CRM using C#.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
 Entity Record = new Entity("new_edRecord");
 Record["new_year"] = "2100";
 Record["new_school"] = new EntityReference("new_school",new Guid("8ba53949-3947-e445-876c-001dd8b71c19"));
 Record["new_gradelevel"] = "100000018";
 organizationProxy.Create(Record);
```

When I execute this, I get the below error:

> Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute):
>   Department.EdRecord.RecordCreate:
>   System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not
>   present in the dictionary.

I double checked to see if a school exist with the GUID by visiting the below url:

```
https://crm.site.com/orgname/api/data/v8.0/new_schools(8ba53949-3947-e445-876c-001dd8b71c19)
```

and this brought a result. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints to see which line is failing in your example? The provided URL, uses "new_schools", and you are using "new_school"

Comment: Yeah, It fails if I add the new_school. it's a mandatory field so it needs to be specified. And the new_schools is used in the upper because CRM uses plural name for rest api

Comment: I would wager that "new_school" is the key which doesn't exist then or if it is a mandatory field, could it be that it is an identity column generated by the insert, and therefore you are not allowed to give it a value?

Comment: Could the problem be with your OptionSet values? You've set `Record["new_year"] = "2100"` but I'm assuming that should be "2010"? You should try to generate strong classes using the CrmSvcUtil tool

Comment: Is the code in your question part of the Department.EdRecord.RecordCreate plugin?

Answer (score 3):

If **new_gradelevel** is an *Optionset* type of field, following should be the code-:

```
Record["new_gradelevel"] = new OptionSetValue(100000018);
```

Also, can you confirm the data type of **new_year** is *String*.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common convention to name CRM lookup fields as the entity name with `id` appended.

Is it possible that `Record["new_school"]` should be `Record["new_schoolid"]`?

OR:

Perhaps the value `100000018` does not exist in the `Record["new_gradelevel"]` optionset. Maybe comment out that line and see what happens.

Comment: yeah I tried that, but then it throwed some error like new_schoolid is not found

Comment: OK, I added another possibility to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like other answers suggested, verify all the field names/schema names for its correctness.

You can do trial & error by commenting out the fields one by one and execute this code to find out the buggy line.

Finally, (this will be my first troubleshooting step) cross check if you have any other plugins on post create of `new_edrecord` entity or associate of `new_school` entity. That synchronous plugin may throw this `KeyNotFoundException`error but bubble here.